# Determining friction force while stirring water

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, friction, water

So I researched a bit on this, and found a video which showed an experiment in which he boiled the water, just by pouring it into a high-speed blender and stirring it. Can someone tell me how can I calculate the amount of friction force which rises the temperature?

Comment: Mixing of a fluid in a blender is a complicated fluid dynamics problem involving viscous forces, inertia, and turbulence.  It can be analyzed quantitatively by using Computational Fluid Dynamics software to solve the non-linear partial differential equations involved in determining the velocity distribution and stresses.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear that there is much of a friction force here. The stirring is adding kinetic energy to the fluid, and since the flow is turbulent eventually the energy becomes random velocities of individual particles, heating the liquid ([an energy cascade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_cascade)). The [turbulence dissipation rate](https://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Turbulence_dissipation_rate) depends on [viscosity](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-27758-0_1669-2.pdf) and the average shear - it is not a simple friction force.

One can also reason backwards. If it takes time $t$ to bring the liquid from temperature $T_1$ (room temperature) to $T_2$ (boiling), and we have mass $M$ liquid, then the energy change must have been $$\Delta E = C M (T_2-T_1)$$ and the power that went into heating it was $\Delta E/t$ Watt (the mixer presumably has a slightly higher power since some of the energy gets turned into sound and other losses). If the rotor has length $L$ and rotates at a frequency $f$ it will on average travel $2\pi L t/2f=\pi Lt/f$ meters during this time. If we assume it experiences a force $F$ resisting it then the total work would be $\pi Lt F/f$ which has to be equal to $\Delta E$. That gives us $$F= C f M (T_2-T_1)/\pi Lt $$ Newtons of force. This is not a friction force as discussed above, but more of a dissipation force where the rotor is being resisted by viscosity -presumably the closest we can get to an answer of the original question.